# Type or namespace name does not exist when build on Travis CI

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, travis-ci

I have a .Net project using NUnit Testing built with Visual Studio 2019, which is working fine on local. But when I push the project to origin/master Github with Travis CI, it was giving me messages like:

`The type or namespace name 'Point' does not exist in the namespace 'Triangle' (are you missing an assembly reference)? [/home/travis/build/phamhoangvu922/TriangleTesting/Triangle.Test/Triangle.Test.csproj]`

I've worked through all of the issues such as making sure all the projects in the workspace are using the same version of .Net for the Target Framework setting etc but not works for me.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You want to make sure you have reference to the project that has the Triangle namespace

Comment: yes, i have, it works fine on local but not works when use Travis CI with Github